# $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \int_{n!^{1/n}}^{(n+1)!^{1/(n+1)}} f(\frac{x}{n}) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}_+^*, \mathbb{R}_+^*)$, what is the value of :
>
> $$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \int_{n!^{1/n}}^{(n+1)!^{1/(n+1)}} f\left (\frac{x}{n}\right) \mathrm{d}x$$

First as $n$ goes to $\infty$ we have : $(n!)^{1/n} \to 1$, so I guess that the value is $0$ except if $f$ is not bounded in a neightboorhood of $0$. If $f$ is not bounded near $0$ it seems that there should be somehow a compensation and maybe the value is $f(1)$ yet I don't at all how to prove this. I've tried change of variables such as : $u = x/n$ yet it doesn't seems to cut it...

Than you !

Comment: Actually $(n!)^{1/n} \sim \frac{n}{e} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) the integral becomes
$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \int_{n/e}^{n/e+1/e} f\left (\frac{x}{n}\right) \mathrm{d}x$$
Using $u=\frac{x}n$ we have $\mathrm{d}u=\frac1n\mathrm{d}x$ and then we are integrating
$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} n\int_{1/e}^{1/e+1/(ne)} f(u) \mathrm{d}u\approx\lim_{n \to + \infty} n\Big(\frac1{ne}\Big)\Big(f\Big(\frac1e\Big)\Big)=\boxed{\frac1ef\Big(\frac1e\Big)}$$

Comment: Would it be possible to do this result by using Mean value theorem and without any approximation?

Comment: I cannot see how, but it may be possible.